# shell find files in current directory only

Tags: shell, find

I am trying to display a list of files from my current folder. The files must be modified within the last n days but - and here comes my problem - they must belong to current folder only. For example, I have a folder: 1. This folder contains a file test.txt and another folder: 11. This folder contains a file: test.txt and another folder 111.

I'm using find -mtime in order to get the files modified within the past n days, but this finds the files recursively - in the subfolders. I need to get only the file from current folder: /1/test.txt.

I tried to use the option -maxdeptx but id doesn't work, it is not recognized.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It is `maxdepth`, not `maxdeptx`.

Comment: use `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime ...`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-prune` primary to prevent recusing into subdirectories.

```
find /1 -prune -mtime ...
```

`-prune` is a standard option; `-maxdepth` is a GNU extension. Note that `-maxdepth 1` and `-prune` are roughly equivalent, that is, `-maxdepth` generalizes the `-prune` primary to support a limited form of directory following.